# Unable to styling asp.net core app to full width

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I've created a new app in Asp.Net Core app, using the Razor Pages template. What I want to do is to expand the main div to be the full width of the screen.

[image: expanddiv]

I've tried the following (Index.cshtml):

```
<div class="full-width shade">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

With the css:

```
.shade {
    background-color: aqua;
}

.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
.full-width {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

And a few other variations, but the div seems to remain centred in the screen. Looking at the dev tools, the container does fill the width, but the `<main>` tag doesn't.

My question is, how can I change this such that the width of the main div always fills to available width of the browser window, but still maintain the functionality that bootstrap gives when dealing with a much smaller screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I change this such that the width of the main div always fills
> to available width of the browser window, but still maintain the
> functionality that bootstrap gives when dealing with a much smaller
> screen?

You could set the body container's `max-width` property to `100%` in the layout page. Please refer the following steps to update your code.

In the `_Layout.cshtml` page (I assume you are using this layout page): add `body-container` in the class attribute.

```
<div class="container body-container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
```

Then, add the following style in the `Index.cshtml`:

```
    <style>
        .shade {
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        .body-container {
            /*remove the container default padding attribute*/
            padding-left: 0px !important;
            padding-right: 0px !important;
            /*increase width as per your need*/
            max-width: 100%;
        } 
    </style>

    <div class="full-width shade">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    </div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

If not remove the container default padding attribute, the result like this:

[image]